# How do I write notification code for android apps which also work on APIs below android 16?

Tags: android

I have the following code for Notification.

```
public void sendBasicNotification(View view) {
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Basic Notification")
        .setContentText("Basic Notification, used earlier")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_share).build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getNotificationManager();
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
 }
```

The above code only works with min Sdk 16. How do I code this for versions below 16? Should I write different code altogether? What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Builder`.

```
public void sendBasicNotification(View view) {
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher_share, "Status message!", System.currentTimeMillis());

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    // you can use different constructors or setLatestEventInfo method to set text, title etc. But it is deprecated after api level 11
    PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, "Your push activity class"), 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Notification Title", "This is the notification message", i);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getNotificationManager();
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use `NotificationCompat.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html), from the Android Support package, which works on API Level 4 and higher.